# Want only domain name from a mail id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple mail ids.

For example:

```
a12_err@gmail.com, fjdjf_123@yahoo.com, hj324_jgfj_12@live.com
```

Required output:

```
gmail, yahoo,live
```

I tried below query for a mail id:

```
select replace(
      subststrong textr('abc_123@gmail.com', instr('abc_123@gmail.com','@')+1),
   '.com','') 
from dual;
```

Could anyone suggest any better solution for it?

Comment: Why do not you use REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Comment: You should also consider other `country code top level domains` as .uk, .de . What is the expected result if `subdomains` included in the email address e.g. `frank@mail.bla.com`

Comment: subdomains are not required in output .